# Validação de CEP Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia.
Preciso validar o CEP digitado em um input. Se o CEP for igual a 35000-000, deve limpar o input e emitir mensagem de CEP Indisponível.
Há como fazer isso usando o atributo pattern do HTML? Como fazer?

```
void validaCEP(){
    var cep = document.commentForm.cep
    if (cep == '35300-000'){
        alert('CEP Indisponível')
        document.commentForm.cep.focus
        alert(cep);
    }
}
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Você tentou fazer alguma coisa? Poderia adicionar na pergunta o real problema? Por que exatamente o CEP citado é inválido? Ele possui a formatação correta de um CEP.

Comment: Regra de negócio.

Comment: Cara, eu uso o https://viacep.com.br/ e funciona muito bem, recomendo. Vai te poupar serviço

Comment: Eu tbm uso, mas nunca precisei fazer esse tipo de validação, com restrição de algum CEP. Preciso barrar o cadastro desse CEP. Há alguma forma de restringir isso no frontend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro, a definição da função está errada. No JavaScript não declaramos o tipo de retorno da função, usamos sempre `function` independente se haverá retorno ou não. Segundo, seu objeto `cep` será o elemento no DOM, uma instância de `HTMLElement`, então nunca será igual a uma *string*, isto é, a condição `cep == '35300-000'` jamais será satisfeita. Como é um `<input>`, é provável que você queira comparar o valor informado no campo, portanto o que você precisa fazer é acessar o atributo `cep.value`.

```js
function validaCEP(){
    var cep = document.commentForm.cep
    if (cep.value == '35300-000'){
        alert('CEP Indisponível');
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="commentForm">
  <input id="cep" type="text" onblur="validaCEP()">
</form>
```

Comment: Muito bom! Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma também é usar a função no evento submit, ou seja, ao tentar submeter o formulário a função irá verificar se o valor do campo possui o valor especificado; se possuir, irá emitir o alert, limpar o campo e abortar o envio do formulário:

```js
var form = document.commentForm;

form.onsubmit = function(){
   
   var cep = form.cep;
   if(cep.value == '35300-000'){
      alert('CEP Indisponível');
      cep.value = ''; // limpa o campo
      return false; // cancela o submit
   }
   
}
```

```html
<form name="commentForm" action="destino.php">
   <input type="text" name="cep" required>
   <br>
   <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```